# Copy URL from Spotify Playlist

Tags: python, tkinter, spotify

I'm trying to make a GUI that takes your Spotify playlist, analyzes it and guesses your age. I'm looking thru their API tutorial and the only way to get the user's playlist is to have them connect using authorization. Is there a way to use the copied link that is available from the share playlist option instead? That seems much more accessible than having them sign into their account each time.

Using python and Tkinter for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless these playlists are public, no, they always will need to AUTH.